# ORACLE - Group By Ten Minutes

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, group-by, date-formatting

I have a time_part columnn in my table which has time format like 13:24 . I want to group by time_part by per 10 minutes. How can I group time by 10 minutes.

**Here is query:**

`SELECT substr(tran_time, 1, 2) || ':' || substr(tran_time, 3, 2) as time_part, recon_date`

**Here is my table and tran_time is='hhmmss'  :**

```
time_part  tran_time recon_date  data
10:14      101425   13/12/2015   a
22:29      222939   13/12/2015   b
22:23      222342   13/12/2015   x
00:46      004615   13/12/2015   d
16:22      162259   13/12/2015   e
12:13      121344   13/12/2015   f
12:14      121410   13/12/2015   g
12:10      121008   13/12/2015   b
21:17      211732   13/12/2015   f
20:25      202511   13/12/2015   r
```

**Example output should be like that**

```
trantime   count(*)
000101     5
001101     4
002101     13
.
.
.
230101     5
231101     23
```

Comment: Extract the minute part, and divide by 10.

Comment: Are `TIME_PART` and `RECON_DATE` string values? If not, why do you separate them?

Comment: time_part's data type is char , recon_date's data type is date.

Comment: date data type always contains part time... So it is really strange way to store date and time

Comment: I updated question. I did not create table and I can not change it but I must solve this problem.

Comment: So tran_time is a char(6) column? Then simply group by the first 3 characters.

Comment: What more do you want, than just the 10 minute intervals? Add extra columns with sample data, and also expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the hour plus 10 minute part in a derived table. Then do `GROUP BY` in the outer table:

```
select 10_min_part, count(*)
from
(
 SELECT substr(tran_time, 1, 3) as 10_min_part
 from tablename
) dt
group by 10_min_part
```

In the SELECT list you can concat `001` to the `10_min_part`. (Right now I can't remember how Oracle does that...)

Comment: But OP said `recon_date` is a DATE data type. Which means `substr` is not required and just use `TO_CHAR` on the date.

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, it is a bad design to store **time portion** separately as **string**.
- Secondly, a **DATE** always has both date and time elements. All you need to do is extract the time portion from the date as and when required using **TO_CHAR** and desired **format model**.

In the comments you said, [time_part's data type is char , recon_date's data type is date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284195/oracle-group-by-ten-minutes#comment56310383_34284195), which means, `recon_date` has both date and time elements. So, you do not need the `SUBSTR`, simply use **TO_CHAR** on the date column.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(recon_date, 'mi'), COUNT(*) 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(recon_date, 'mi');
```